# Best way to create fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some fragments with a gridview, gridview contents are decided from a where in the db, througth a cursor loader.
So, fragments are equal except for db query: I need a constructor-like way to impose the difference.
My solution is to put arguments in a bundle and then call

```
Fragment.instantiate(this,clss.getName(), newTab.args)
```

where args is a Bundle containing a String-where and a StringArray-whereArgs is it the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, there is nothing wrong with this approach,

other thing you can do is pass the where args in the constructors as well

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create new fragments is to add a methode in the fragment for instantiation, for example following:

```
public static DetailFragment newInstance(String id) {
    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_ITEM, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return(fragment);
}
```

Then when you need the data you do something like following:

```
this.getArguments().getString(KEY_ITEM);
```